# Find rectangular equation of a cardioid

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

Given the equation in polar form $$r = 1 - \sin\theta,$$ find the rectangular equation.

So far, I found:

$$x^2 + y^2 = 1 - 2\sin\theta + \sin^2\theta\quad x = \cos\theta - \sin\theta\cos\theta\quad y = \sin\theta - \sin^2\theta$$

Where should I go from here?

Comment: You may multiply your polar equation through by $ \ r \ $ to get $ \ r^2 = r - r \sin \theta \ , $ and then write $ \ x^2 + y^2 = r - y \ . $ Then solve for $ \ r \ $ in this equation, square both sides again, and replace the resulting $ \ r^2 \ $ with $ \ x^2 + y^2 \  $ and simplify (as much as can be managed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that $y = r\sin{\theta} \Rightarrow \sin{\theta} = \frac{y}{r}$.  This gives us:
$$
r = 1 - \frac{y}{r}
$$
Now, multiplying by $r$ on each side, we get:
$$
r^2 = r - y
$$
Noting that $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, so this is the same as
$$
x^2 + y^2 = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - y 
$$
You can do what you wish from there to simplify it: I'm not sure what form you want it in.

Comment: I'll mention that the more conventional form for the Cartesian equation is $ \ (x^2 + y^2 + y)^2 \ = \ x^2 + y^2 \ . $ [See references such as http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html .]  The linear term "y" , instead of "x", appears in this equation because we have a cardioid symmetrical about the $ \ y-$ axis, rather than the $ \ x-$ axis.